# Could not allocate new session in SSL session shared cache "le_nginx_SSL" while SSL handshaking

Tags: nginx, centos, ssl, certbot

I have a centos 8 server with nginx and certbot installed. When I check:

`cat /var/log/nginx/error.log`

I get this error a lot:

`[alert] 2245236#0: *42902735 could not allocate new session in SSL session shared cache "le_nginx_SSL" while SSL handshaking, client: ip, server: ip`

Would you know how to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you solved it? Same issue here.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issued and solved it by increasing the cache size:

```
ssl_session_cache shared: le_nginx_SSL:20m; # before 10m
```

You can try to reduce `ssl_session_timeout`to delete quicker the sessions.

reference: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_cache

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).